# SVG not appearing in Firefox

Tags: html, svg

I'm at a loss as far as why the SVG below isn't visible at all in Firefox. I'm not seeing any issues in dev tools and tweaking different values had no effect. Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
<svg id="c3c12b3e-0f10-494e-be13-9dfc6fbf4623" style="width: 65px; height: 65px;" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 74 74">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="cb61f87d-92e3-4956-b0ac-b85f54e2e619">
            <rect x="651" y="352" width="64" height="64" fill="none"></rect>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="652f7fcb-18a1-4608-9813-6592b340c183" transform="translate(-646 -347)">
            <path d="M683,416a32,32,0,1,0-32-32,32,32,0,0,0,32,32Z" fill="none" clip-path="url(#cb61f87d-92e3-4956-b0ac-b85f54e2e619)"
                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="694f7d6a-8be8-46f7-8cd1-9190b8d68dd7" transform="translate(-646 -347)">
            <path d="M683.5,413A28.5,28.5,0,1,0,655,384.5,28.5,28.5,0,0,0,683.5,413Z" fill="none" clip-path="url(#cb61f87d-92e3-4956-b0ac-b85f54e2e619)"
                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="60eff4e7-8ba1-4edf-ab4c-6ddd26ac9a96" transform="translate(-646 -347)">
            <path d="M668,399.91c.53-.32.88-.49,1.18-.71,2-1.5,4.86-2.18,5.14-5.36,0-.38.63-.71,1-1.07l4.27-4.51-1.87-1.9-.79.69c-2.26,1.93-3.64,5-7,5.44a.67.67,0,0,0-.36.31l-3.29,5,1.79,2.07Zm16.81-21.36,8-8a6,6,0,0,1,1-.87.72.72,0,0,1,.7,0,.69.69,0,0,1,0,.67,6.71,6.71,0,0,1-.89,1l-8,8,1.45,1.36c1.6-1.67,3.09-3.31,4.68-4.86a35.08,35.08,0,0,1,4.61-4.35c.2.22.41.44.61.67l-9.31,9.33,1.35,1.26c3.07-3,6.12-5.87,9-8.88a3.78,3.78,0,0,0-.26-5.43,3.87,3.87,0,0,0-5.33-.18c-3,2.89-5.86,5.93-8.85,9l1.25,1.33ZM666.41,372c-1.78,5.91,2.46,11.06,8,10.56a2.94,2.94,0,0,1,2.06.77c5.08,5,10.1,10,15.13,15.05,1.23,1.23,2.62,1.95,4.39,1.41,3.12-.94,3.88-4.54,1.43-7q-7.5-7.59-15.11-15.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1-.91-2.41,7.57,7.57,0,0,0-4.93-7.81,7.27,7.27,0,0,0-5.41,0c1.13,1.1,2.08,2,3,2.89,3,2.95,3,3-.1,6-1.4,1.33-2.09,1.37-3.43,0s-2.58-2.76-4.1-4.39Z"
                fill="none" clip-path="url(#cb61f87d-92e3-4956-b0ac-b85f54e2e619)" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <title>icon_settings_green</title>
    <g clip-path="url(#652f7fcb-18a1-4608-9813-6592b340c183)">
        <rect width="74" height="74" fill="#afe6af"></rect>
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(#694f7d6a-8be8-46f7-8cd1-9190b8d68dd7)">
        <rect x="4" y="4" width="67" height="67" fill="#c2edc4"></rect>
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(#60eff4e7-8ba1-4edf-ab4c-6ddd26ac9a96)">
        <rect x="15" y="15" width="43" height="43" fill="#fff"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try "optimizing" the svg with this tool: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/   - It reduces svgs to their simplest possible path and transform representations, and in doing so, often solves compatibility issues between browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `clipPath`s 2-4 reference path 1. Now, paths 2-4 are `transform`ed, which raises a question of what coordinates should path 1 use? The original coordinates before the transform (around `650,350`, as in your example), or the coordinates after the transform (around `0,0`)?

I don't know what the spec says, but Firefox thinks it should be the latter. So if you change the first `clipPath` to..

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64" fill="none"></rect>
```

..it will work in Firefox (but fail in other browsers).

But I don't understand why you need that second layer of clipping anyway. To make something that works in all browsers, simply remove that first path altogether:

```html
<svg id="c3c12b3e-0f10-494e-be13-9dfc6fbf4623" style="width: 65px; height: 65px;" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 74 74">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="652f7fcb-18a1-4608-9813-6592b340c183" transform="translate(-646 -347)">
            <path d="M683,416a32,32,0,1,0-32-32,32,32,0,0,0,32,32Z" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="694f7d6a-8be8-46f7-8cd1-9190b8d68dd7" transform="translate(-646 -347)">
            <path d="M683.5,413A28.5,28.5,0,1,0,655,384.5,28.5,28.5,0,0,0,683.5,413Z" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="60eff4e7-8ba1-4edf-ab4c-6ddd26ac9a96" transform="translate(-646 -347)">
            <path d="M668,399.91c.53-.32.88-.49,1.18-.71,2-1.5,4.86-2.18,5.14-5.36,0-.38.63-.71,1-1.07l4.27-4.51-1.87-1.9-.79.69c-2.26,1.93-3.64,5-7,5.44a.67.67,0,0,0-.36.31l-3.29,5,1.79,2.07Zm16.81-21.36,8-8a6,6,0,0,1,1-.87.72.72,0,0,1,.7,0,.69.69,0,0,1,0,.67,6.71,6.71,0,0,1-.89,1l-8,8,1.45,1.36c1.6-1.67,3.09-3.31,4.68-4.86a35.08,35.08,0,0,1,4.61-4.35c.2.22.41.44.61.67l-9.31,9.33,1.35,1.26c3.07-3,6.12-5.87,9-8.88a3.78,3.78,0,0,0-.26-5.43,3.87,3.87,0,0,0-5.33-.18c-3,2.89-5.86,5.93-8.85,9l1.25,1.33ZM666.41,372c-1.78,5.91,2.46,11.06,8,10.56a2.94,2.94,0,0,1,2.06.77c5.08,5,10.1,10,15.13,15.05,1.23,1.23,2.62,1.95,4.39,1.41,3.12-.94,3.88-4.54,1.43-7q-7.5-7.59-15.11-15.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1-.91-2.41,7.57,7.57,0,0,0-4.93-7.81,7.27,7.27,0,0,0-5.41,0c1.13,1.1,2.08,2,3,2.89,3,2.95,3,3-.1,6-1.4,1.33-2.09,1.37-3.43,0s-2.58-2.76-4.1-4.39Z" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <title>icon_settings_green</title>
    <g clip-path="url(#652f7fcb-18a1-4608-9813-6592b340c183)">
        <rect width="74" height="74" fill="#afe6af"></rect>
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(#694f7d6a-8be8-46f7-8cd1-9190b8d68dd7)">
        <rect x="4" y="4" width="67" height="67" fill="#c2edc4"></rect>
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(#60eff4e7-8ba1-4edf-ab4c-6ddd26ac9a96)">
        <rect x="15" y="15" width="43" height="43" fill="#fff"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Sphinxx's answer (which you should accept), you can get rid of the unnecessary `<clipPath>` elements altogether.

Did you use Illustrator to create this icon?  It produces really bloated SVGs.

```html
<svg id="c3c12b3e-0f10-494e-be13-9dfc6fbf4623" style="width: 65px; height: 65px;" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 74 74">
    <title>icon_settings_green</title>
    <g transform="translate(-646 -347)">
        <path d="M683,416a32,32,0,1,0-32-32,32,32,0,0,0,32,32Z" fill="#afe6af"/>
        <path d="M683.5,413A28.5,28.5,0,1,0,655,384.5,28.5,28.5,0,0,0,683.5,413Z" fill="#c2edc4"/>
        <path d="M668,399.91c.53-.32.88-.49,1.18-.71,2-1.5,4.86-2.18,5.14-5.36,0-.38.63-.71,1-1.07l4.27-4.51-1.87-1.9-.79.69c-2.26,1.93-3.64,5-7,5.44a.67.67,0,0,0-.36.31l-3.29,5,1.79,2.07Zm16.81-21.36,8-8a6,6,0,0,1,1-.87.72.72,0,0,1,.7,0,.69.69,0,0,1,0,.67,6.71,6.71,0,0,1-.89,1l-8,8,1.45,1.36c1.6-1.67,3.09-3.31,4.68-4.86a35.08,35.08,0,0,1,4.61-4.35c.2.22.41.44.61.67l-9.31,9.33,1.35,1.26c3.07-3,6.12-5.87,9-8.88a3.78,3.78,0,0,0-.26-5.43,3.87,3.87,0,0,0-5.33-.18c-3,2.89-5.86,5.93-8.85,9l1.25,1.33ZM666.41,372c-1.78,5.91,2.46,11.06,8,10.56a2.94,2.94,0,0,1,2.06.77c5.08,5,10.1,10,15.13,15.05,1.23,1.23,2.62,1.95,4.39,1.41,3.12-.94,3.88-4.54,1.43-7q-7.5-7.59-15.11-15.07a2.74,2.74,0,0,1-.91-2.41,7.57,7.57,0,0,0-4.93-7.81,7.27,7.27,0,0,0-5.41,0c1.13,1.1,2.08,2,3,2.89,3,2.95,3,3-.1,6-1.4,1.33-2.09,1.37-3.43,0s-2.58-2.76-4.1-4.39Z" fill="#fff" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's coming from Illustrator unfortunately. You're right about the bloat. I always seem to experience these issues with Illustrator/SVG exporting. Thanks.